# Executed piped commands via System.Diagnostics.Process on Mono

Tags: c#, mono

Is it possible to execute the following piped commands via `System.Diagnostics.Process`?

```
echo "test" | sudo -S shutdown -r +1
```

I've tried setting the file name to "/bin/bash", with the above as arguments, with no success.

```
...
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = "/bin/bash", Arguments = "echo \"test\" | sudo -S shutdown -r +1" };
process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`bash` is interpreting your command as a file name followed by arguments, meaning it invokes `echo` and passes all the rest (including the pipe `|`) to it for printing so you will get `test | sudo -S shutdown -r +1` echoed and `sudo` won't be executed.

You should use the `-c` option to execute a command. Furthermore, you should quote the command itself so that it gets passed as a single argument. Something like this should work:

```c#
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "/bin/bash",
    Arguments = "-c \"echo test | sudo -S shutdown -r +1\""
};
```

Comment: This method exposes your root password, since it will create a process like "/bin/bash -c echo test | sudo -S  shutdown -r +1", so if you run "ps aux" anyone can see it, or log it.

Comment: Yes, it will expose the user's password, and it's kinda pointless to use `echo` when you can write to the pipe yourself.